# is calling flutterTts.setStartHandler() method in onPressed callback of button in flutter is good practice?(flutter_tts plugin)

Tags: flutter, dart, text-to-speech, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

Scenario: I have set of children built using Listview.builder in which every child has button. Now i want when particular index of child pressed TTS(text to speech) method should be called. Implementing this is not problem. But flutter_tts plugin provides setStartHandler, setCompletionHandler methods which is called whenever tts starts and complete its work. But both that method cant be placed in initState since they need access to index variable.

```
body: ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: litems.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return Column(children:[RaisedButton(onPressed:(){
flutterTts.setStartHandler(() {
  setState(() {
    ttsState = TtsState.playing;
    litems[index].isPlaying = true;
  });
});

flutterTts.setCompletionHandler(() {
  setState(() {
    ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
    litems[index].isPlaying = false;
  });
});
//custom speak() method which invokes TTS
_speak(litems[index].text);
//rest of the code

},
child:widget)
,],
);
    }
  )
```

Above code is just example.
please tell me is this good approach or is there any better solution
Thanks in advance